# LibGDX Allow Player to Walk Over Transparency in Block2D Shape

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, transparency, shapes

I'm creating an overhead game right now, but I am running into a small issue. I've finished making some of the tiles in a tileset blocking, but the issue that occurs when I set blocking tiles is that transparent tiles are set to fully block. I would like it so that the transparency is not totally blocked off, and the player can walk over it.

Here's the character at the exact corner between two tiles that are blocking.
[image: Problem]

Here's some code.

```
public void loadTiles() {
  BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
  FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
  TiledMapTileLayer layer  = (TiledMapTileLayer) tileMap.getLayers().get("tiles");
  for(int row = 0; row < layer.getHeight(); row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < layer.getWidth(); col++) {
      //get cell
      Cell cell = layer.getCell(col, row);
      if(cell == null) continue;
      if(cell.getTile() == null) continue;
      int id = cell.getTile().getId();
      //will store an array with the id values
      if(id != 122 && id != 123 && id != 154 && id != 155) {
        //body and fixture
        bdef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        bdef.position.set((((col * tileWidth) + 16) / Values.PPM) - (8 / Values.PPM) , (((row * tileHeight) + 16) / Values.PPM) - (8 / Values.PPM));

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(8 / Values.PPM, 8 / Values.PPM);

        fdef.friction = 0;
        fdef.shape = shape;
        fdef.filter.categoryBits = Values.BIT_NPC;
        fdef.filter.maskBits = Values.BIT_PLAYER;
        fdef.isSensor = false;
        world.createBody(bdef).createFixture(fdef);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The tiles are loaded separately, and the Box2D bodies are drawn over the tiles. Here's that code if you want it.

```
tileMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("/path/to/map/level1.tmx");
tmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap);
```

And simply, in the render method, tmr.render() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a design question with multiple possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

Fixtures generated at runtime from transparency.

There are algorithms that can generate polygons from the opaque parts of images with transparency.

This is complex and more error prone. What if you have a semitransparent part like a shadow and the algorithm misclassifies that part as being blocking?

**Solution 2**

Fixtures are created for each tile type in an editor like PhysicsEditor.

More flexible than runtime generation. You can tweak and optimize the polygon shapes manually.

**Solution 3**

Create tags for special tiles in the map editor and then create the custom fixtures in code.

Types:

- Bottom left corner.
- Top Right Corner.
- Etc.

**Solution 4**

I'm guessing there is a way to add arbitrary attributes to types of tiles.

You could have stored on your tile type values that describe a few rectangles representing the opaque parts.

Example attributes:

```
// Bottom Left Tile Attributes

// Rect 1
// Position (Top Left of rectangle, (1.0, 1.0) is top right of image)
r1x = 0.0
r1y = 1.0
// Size (Percent of tile size)
r1w = 0.1
r1h = 1.0

// Rect 2
// Position
r2x = 0.0
r2y = 0.1
// Size
r2w = 1.0
r2h = 0.1
```

Then read these attributes and construct the fixtures.

This works as long as your shapes can be represented by a few rectangles.

**Which One?**

They're not written in order of practicality. I think 1 is probably the worst actually, but it does most directly address making only the non-transparent parts blocked off

- If you are going to want irregular shapes in the future 2 is the way to go.
- If you only have a few kinds of tiles 3 is the way to go.
- If you have more types of tiles but the shapes can be described using only a few rectangles 4 would work.

If you want to do 1 this link is relevant:

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/03/13/from-png-to-box2d-first-attempt/ .

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info! I do have one question - how would I go about doing solution one? I have no experience with Box2D or LibGDX, so I don't know. I tried googling, but I did not come across a solution.

Comment: It's not simple. Those suggestions aren't in order of how well I think they might work for you. I think 1 is probably the worst actually, but it does most directly address making the transparent parts blocked off so I wrote it first.

Answer (score 0):

Set `isSensor = true;` for `FixtureDef` of tile you want to be transparent, it will still respond to contacts in `ContactListener`, but it will be "transparent" and player will be able  move threw it.

Comment: I want only the transparent parts to be non blocking. I want the wall part to be blocking, but the transparent area on that wall tile to be non blocking. So this would not work, as it makes the whole tile non blocking.

Comment: If so you need create different Fixture for the part you want make transparent and make this Fixture isSensor=true

Comment: What do you suggest I do? Create a new fixture for all opaque pixels? Or would that get laggy somehow?